# How to download file in ruby with link like https://data.gov.in/resources/all-india-pincode-directory/download

Tags: ruby, net-http

I want to download file which gets downloaded on opening the page with link https://data.gov.in/resources/all-india-pincode-directory/download in ruby

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you,

```
puts " download start"
   url = 'https://data.gov.in/resources/all-india-pincode-directory/download '


    open('all_india_pin_code.csv', 'wb') do |file|
      file << open(url).read
    end

    puts " download end"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard library called Open URI...Did you try that?

```
require 'open-uri'
file = open("https://data.gov.in/resources/all-india-pincode-directory/download")
```